# 1 button on page accidently restricted by lack of form data in a completely different form on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, button

Basically there is a sign up button and a log in button on the same page and when you click the log in button the AJAX request will not be sent because the sign up form's data has not been filled.. very annoying

```
*****edited for clarification purposes*****

function restrict(elem){
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if(elem == "email"){
        rx = /[' "]/gi;
    } else if(elem == "username"){
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function checkusername(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    if(u != ""){
        _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
function signup(){
    var f = _("firstname").value;
    var l = _("lastname").value;
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if(f == "" || l == "" || u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == ""){
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else if(p1 != p2){
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
    } else if( _("terms").style.display == "none"){
        status.innerHTML = "Please view the terms of use";
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("f="+f+"&l="+l+"&u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g);
    }
}
function openTerms(){
    _("terms").style.display = "block";
    emptyElement("status");
}
/*new script*/
</script><script>
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function login(){
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p = _("password").value;
    if(e == "" || p == ""){
        _("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("sttus").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    _("sttus").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, please try again.";
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.location = "user.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
```

#### get element by id function:

```
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function toggleElement(x){
    var x = _(x);
    if(x.style.display == 'block'){
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

#### AJAX framework:

```
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open( meth, url, true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;    
    }
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<body>
<?php include_once("template_pageTop.php"); ?>
<!--sign up form div-->
<div id="pageMiddle">
  <h3>Sign Up Here</h3>
  <form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>First Name: </div>
    <input id="firstname" id name="f" type="text" maxlength="16">
         <div>Last Name: </div>
    <input id="lastname" id name="l" type="text" maxlength="16">
        <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="username" id name="u" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>   
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="email" id name="e" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">

    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" id name="p" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100">

    <div>Gender:</div>
    <select id="gender" id name="g" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <option value="m">Male</option>
      <option value="f">Female</option>
      <option value="o">Other</option>
    </select>
    <div>Country:</div>
    <select id="country" id name="c" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <?php include_once("php_includes/country_option.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <div>
      <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="openTerms()">
        View the Terms Of Use
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="terms" style="display:none;">
      <h3>itsyourquarter Terms Of Use</h3>
      <p>We here at itsyourquarter.com fully understand that you may have things you find funny and offensive</p>
      <p>but won't post it in fear of being judged and ridiculed.</p>
      <p>We here at itsyourquarter.com we know, We just don't care!</p>
      <p>We take great pride in any form of sense of humor without the negativity through censorship. We enjoy</p>
      <p>Some raunchy and controversial topics, So not only do we welcome it, we encourage it!</p>
      <p>So feel free, post it here, maybe some one else will find it funny.... Maybe they will be offended here</p>
      <p>who cares post it anyway and have a great day!</p>
      <p>that being said the first and only rule at itsyourquarter.com is</p>
      <p>1. you dont talk about fight club</p>
      <p>2. if you suggest any other rules you might possibly be permabanned</p>
      <p>3. have a good day</p>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
    <span id="status"></span>
  </form>
  <!--sign in form div-->
<div id="pM">
  <h3>Log In Here</h3>
  <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
  <form method="post" form id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input type="text" id="email"  name id="e" onfocus="emptyElement('sttus')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Password:</div>
    <input type="password" id="password"  name id="p" onfocus="emptyElement('sttus')" maxlength="100">
    <br /><br />
    <button id="loginbtn" onclick="login()">Log In</button> 
    <p id="sttus"></p>
    <a href="forgotpassword.php">Forgot Your Password?</a>
  </form>
  <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
</div>
</div>

<!--bottom breaks-->
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<?php include_once("template_pageBottom.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't make it pretty in the CSS yet because I can't seem to get the forms to submit when they were combined together.

Comment: your HTML would help

Comment: sorry @JaromandaX i figured the problem was in the javascript. i have added it

Comment: i have no http limiters they are all in javascript and php but the php error it sends off is different thenthe one javascript sends off. this is how i have narrowed it down to the javascript

Comment: ive changed everything that said status in the new javascript and html to sttus and now its appearing in the correct spot however still not submiting because the sign up form is not filled. i believe im on the right track but still at a loss

Comment: you have two `input id="email"` for a start

Comment: `<input type="text" id="email"  name id="e"` two id's and an empty name attribute .... `<input type="password" id="password"  name id="p"` two id's and an empty name attribute again ... `<form method="post" form id="loginform"` what is a form attribute? You should look into a HTML validator because your HTML is not

Comment: omg lol im so stupid. i merged the two forms and didn't even realize they had the same names sorry. thanks for pointing that out. i had sort of put it to the side because i have a few projects im working on... yeah its as you said i just put an extra l and d at the end of them in javascript and html and it works again. thank u.. my cell phone testers were advising me to merge the forms and i didn't realize that you couldn't have the same ids for values in separate forms. my mistake